# Android action bar home

Tags: java, android, annotations, android-actionbar

Simple enough,

At the top left hand corner of the action bar sits the default icon for the application. In most apps, it is clicked and returns you to the homepage. I'm working with 2 devices, a 3.2 and a 2.3.3 and I am trying to implement the action bar on the 3.2 without affecting the other.

I imagine its implemented like this:

```
case android.R.id.home:            
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActOnThisActivity.class);            
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
         startActivity(intent);            
         return true;
```

One last thing is to set the flag

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

This should work but as anyone familiar with android will know, this cant be run on an API of 11 or below. So it will run on 3.2+ but not the 2.3.3. Is there a way to specify this method to only work on api11 and above?

NOTE that @TargetApi(11) annotation might work but I've had some weird errors with it.

Comment: Since there is no action bar on Android 2.3.3, what are you using for an action bar implementation? ActionBarSherlock? Something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare By default, there is no action bar on the phone. They are inserted into the options menu button instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to specify this method to only work on api11 and above?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
  getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Was not aware that Build.*** even existed. I'm sure if i use that sparingly, it'll come in very handy. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at `ActionBarCompat` from the sdk samples will give you fair idea of how to do it.

The following code in the `ActionBarHelper` class(from the sample) decides the instance for different versions.

```
public static ActionBarHelper createInstance(Activity activity) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        return new ActionBarHelperICS(activity);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        return new ActionBarHelperHoneycomb(activity);
    } else {
        return new ActionBarHelperBase(activity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you use `ActionBarCompat` when you can just use `ActionBarSherlock`...? It's so much better in almost every possible way.

Comment: @AlexLockwood ActionBarSherlock is not an option for this unfortunately. If it was then my job would be done :I

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at ActionbarSherlock - I use it in a few apps and it works flawlessly. Mimics the Action Bar perfectly in Android versions below Honeycomb (3.0).

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

> Main API for nearly all interaction with the action bar. This is the exact API *getSupportActionBar()* exposes.

Comment: Already ran it by the lead, he says no for this. Long story but there are reasons. Appreciate the answer anyway

Comment: Alright - fair enough. If he does change his mind this is probably the best library out there for ActionBar support below 3.0